# I can't use methods from another class from imported libraries in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio

I used

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.macroyau:thingspeakandroid:0.2.0'
}
```

to download the external libraries I need. I created an instance of one of the classes of the lib and upon calling the methods, it seems I can only call the interfaces instead of the actual methods as you can see
here!

[image]

It's the first time I am using Android Studio, is it the right way to import external libraries?

Comment: try restarting android-studio and rebuilding project

Answer (score 0):

Properly add the library by adding new module in android studio
File->New->New Module->Android Library
Choose the path where you downloaded the library.

Then add the dependency and rebuild it.
Check the errors if any